# pyplot not working in python 3.3 windows

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 36, in <module>
from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 22, in <module>
import matplotlib.dates as _  # <-registers a date unit converter
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 119, in <module>
from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\dateutil\rrule.py", line 18, in <module>
from six import advance_iterator, integer_types
ImportError: No module named 'six'
>>>
```

I tried to import matplotlib.pyplot in python 3.3 in windows 7, got above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dependency, namely 'six'.

You can get it through pip:

```
pip install six
```

or from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#six